# Use the verb "to mothball" in official texts

Tags: word-usage, idioms, legalese, register, terminology

I saw a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Standardization) (and not only this one) using the verb "*to mothball*" to denote rather obsolete, abandoned, put-on-hold methods or phenomena, e.g.:

> So by 2003, the original ECMAScript 4 work was **mothballed**.

Is the usage of a phrase like "*to mothball something*" or "*X is mothballed since Y*" is appropriate in formal context, e.g. in technical documentation, legal papers or in a scientific manuscript?

Also, is this verb is used for people or animals?

Comment: The idiom is a little informal. In a rigorously academic setting, I'd look for words more illustrative of your erudition, like _deprecated_ or _superannuated_.

Comment: The [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/mothball) entry for *mothball* includes several example usages (most of which are gleaned from news articles), so it's at least used in journalism.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank you for your suggestion, these are great substituents. And you are right, I never saw this expression in academic setting, it might 
be just too vulgar. Could you please post your comment as an answer and include a note whether one is allowed to use this term for people in colloquial speech?

Comment: You could use **mothballed** when testifying before Congress about a military project but not to describe a metrical prayer a saint was working on but set aside.  It's fine for ECMAScript and other motheaten things. It's a question of register.

Comment: Deprecation is not the same as mothballing. When something is deprecated it is likely to be removed from later versions. Something that is mothballed is simply made inactive with the intention of later revival.

Comment: @RobK True, and the verb _mothball_ was misused in the cited Wikipedia article. By the way, have you ever smelled mothballs?

Comment: I wouldn't say "mothballed" is vulgar. In case you don't know, the term does not refer to the insect's teeny-weeny genitalia, but to a common form of chemical repellant.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have. They are useful for making a shed inhospitable to a skunk, if you can imagine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a perfectly acceptable term in English. The term derives from the small balls of pesticide added to closets and drawers to repel and kill moths, which would otherwise damage the stored clothing. See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mothball So when you mothball something, you put it away for long term storage.

Comment: Thank you, I'm more or less aware of the origins of this expression, but I still have some doubts about it's usage in a formal document.

Comment: I can't imagine what sort of formal document I wouldn't use it in.

Comment: @RobK As Tᴚoɯɐuo says, it's a question of register. It's not that the term is inappropriate or "vulgar"; it's that others may be more "learned" in affect.